# change navigation properties gwt openlayers

Tags: gwt, properties, navigation, openlayers

In my gwt application I make use of gwt-openlayers library.
To disable the navigation control one can do something like:

```
Control control = getMap().getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.Navigation");
control.deactivate();
```

This will prevent zoom, double click, drag, etc.
Is there any way I can prevent just the zoom (mouse wheel and double click)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zoom on mouse wheel is a property that can be changed like:

```
NavigationOptions navOptions = new NavigationOptions();
navOptions.setZoomWheelEnabled(false);
```

But I did not find a way to prevent the zoom on double click.

I end up preventing the zoom by calling:

```
map.setMinMaxZoomLevel(minZoomLevel, maxZoomLevel)
```

and apply the same value for both minZoomLevel and maxZoomLevel.